# Is it possible to mount a TrueCrypt volume to a NTFS mount point?

Tags: windows, mount, ntfs, truecrypt

The question is simple really.

Under Linux etc.. you can mount TrueCrypt volumes, files or partitions, to any mount point of your choosing whereas in Windows the interface only shows drive letters.

I'm wondering if I can mount the volume, a partition in this case, un-encrypted to a NTFS mount point, or folder, instead of using drive letters.

The reason I ask is I am running out of letters :(.

I'm using Server 2008 with the latest TrueCrypt install.

Note: I know how to mount a volume directly to an NTFS folder mount point but doing so, and navigating to the mount point, prompts a notice saying the volume is not formatted - to be expected as the volume is not un-encrypted at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, after much research and looking at the documentation it is not possible through the TrueCrypt interface.

There is a hack out there that allows you to change the mount point once mounted but the letter the mount was using is unusable until you unmount the volume. Pointless really.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the entire disk instead of partions. When opening drive manager, that will make Windows "offer" to initialize (and add drive letter) the disks that are not initialized. To this you should of course click cancel. Those not initialized disks will have no drive letter and when mounted in Truecrypt they will only occupy one drive letter per disk.

In drive manager you also have the choice to change drive letter on disks and volumes. Theoretically you also have the choice to choose change and then remove drive letter. I have not tested this option, so I would strongly advice you to do a backup of the contents before you test it.